# Using SMuFL-compliant music fonts with lilypond-book in 2022

Tags: lilypond

[Lilypond](https://lilypond.org/) is a program for typesetting sheet music, which can be integrated to LaTeX through lilypond-book. The source a music document combining the two looks [like this](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/usage/an-example-of-a-musicological-document):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{lilypond}[fragment,quote,staffsize=26,verbatim]
  c'4 f16
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to use SMuFL-compliant music fonts (such as [Leland](https://github.com/MuseScoreFonts/Leland)) with lilypond-book? Also, is it possible to select a text font for lilypond by directly pointing to an otf file, instead of following the setup outlined [in this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123486)?

Comment: (The "2022" in the title is because there were a number of different solutions for this at some point ([example](https://github.com/lyp-packages/smufl)), but many of them have since been deprecated, or had their development halted.)

Comment: As I see this, this is a lilypond question. You should rather ask this in the music theory forum on stack exchange. Everything between `begin{lilypond}` and `end{lilypond}` belongs to there. Is your problem the font of the note heads and stems or the text of the song text below the notes?